# Promises in foreach

Tags: javascript, node.js, foreach, promise

I have a couple of code about some logic.

My following code block working as expected so `willbeUpdated` variable couldn't updated literally in syncronized way.

```
var willbeUpdated = 1;
anArray.forEach(function(i){
   getPromisedData(i).then(function(d){
       willbeUpdated += d;
   });

});
if (wiillbeUpdated == something) {
  // some logic
}
```

So question is that, Do I have to create again another promised method for that foreach logic and put `outside if logic` its then method, will be a best practise, or any other preferable idea in this situation ?

Edit: I asked this question to hear best or better approaches about nested async function handling instead of exact code blocks, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

```
var willbeUpdated = 1,
    promises = [];
anArray.forEach(function(i){
   promises.push(getPromisedData(i));
});
Promise.all(promises).then(function() {
  // some logic
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is to put the if block (`willBeUpdated == something`) inside the function that the `getPromisedData` resolves with.

So:

```
var willbeUpdated = 1;
anArray.forEach(function(i){
   getPromisedData(i).then(function(d){
       willbeUpdated += d;
       if (wiillbeUpdated == something) {
         // some logic
       }
   });

});
```

Would work out. If you can give me a better idea of what you're trying to do then there may be a better solution.

Comment: In the case of simple incrementation, it could work, but will not wait for all the tasks to end and will do something before finished with the tasks.

Comment: In this way , if logic will run as array length count.

Answer (score 1):

`q` and many other promise libraries can handle promise arrays, and wait for their result.

```
var q = require('q');
var willbeUpdated = 1;
var todo = [];

anArray.forEach(function(i){
  todo.push(getPromisedData(i).then(function(d) {
    return (willbeUpdated+= d);
  }));
});

q(todo).then(function() {
  if (wiillbeUpdated == something) {
    // some logic
  }      
});
```

Comment: Your and @Gothdo's answers seems ok, but the problem is not code exactly, for instance, in nested loops It will be ugly pushing promises return values to get its latest value, is this solution the only way?